# how to optimize mysql query if i have too many OR operators in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

using PHP and MySQL

i have grabbed an array of facebook user ids from facebook.

Now i want to find the corresponding username in my application for this array.

Clearly in my application the user table contains unique username and unique fb_uid values.

my rudimentary understanding oof programming led me to 2 ways:

1) use a loop and run through the array of fb_uid and find the username one by one.

OR

2) create a monster query like select distinct(username) from users where fb_uid = value1 OR fb_uid = value2 ...

so is there a better way out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use SQL's `IN` operator instead:

```
select distinct(username) from users where fb_uid in (value1, value2, ...)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 1):

If your list of fb_uids is big *(say, more than 100 or 500 r 1000 hundred ids)*, I wouldn't go with the "or" way : too many "or" like this will hurt the DB, I think.

But doing one query per id is not really good either...

So what about a mix of those two ideas ? Doing one query per, say, 50 or 100 fb_uids ?

And, instead of using lots or OR, you can go with IN ; a bit like this :

```
select distinct(username) from users where fb_uid IN (id1, id2, id3, ...)
```

Not sure it'll change anything for the DB, but, at least, it's looking better ^^

Only thing is you shouldn't use too many ids in the IN ; so, doing a couple of queries, with between 50 and 500 ids each time might be the way to go.

And to help you a bit further, you might need to take a look at [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice), to extracts "slices" of your fb_uids array...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in - According to that link, the max number of values for IN in MySQL is limited only by the max_packet_size.  So... how many values you stick in there can probably be quite large, but testing might be required to find out _how_ large.  Other than that, I like your answer: +1.

Comment: I supposed that could have some impact on performances -- that's actually more the reason for which I thought about not putting too many values inside the IN() ; though, I have to admit I didn't do any benchmarks on MySQL about that ^^

Answer (score 0):

**There's another MySQL function: MATCH AGAINST**

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE status = 1 AND MATCH (person, city, company, zipcode, tags) AGAINST ('".$searchstring."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Your inputstring will be searched in different columns.

Maybe you can reconsider your sql statement if you didn't knew this function.